# Check whether a number is in a string range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, split, between

I have a table

| `ID` | `Count` | `Range` |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 33 | 1-100 |
| 2 | 120 | 101-200 |
| 3 | 155 | 201-300 |

The `Range` is a string that can only have the values `1-100`, `101-200`, `201-300`. I need to write a query that checks whether the count and the range fits, so 155 should pop up.

My idea was:

```sql
select * 
from Tabe
where Count between (select value from string_split(Range, '-'))
```

but this does not work. Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: I would _highly_ disencourage naming a column `Count` as this is a SQL function keyword

Comment: Idealy fix your design here, don't have a `varchar` column with a value like `'1-100'` have 2 `int` columns, `RangeStart` and `RangeEnd` with the values `1` and `100` respectively. Fix the design, fix the problem.

Comment: And also your query has to make sure that `RangeStart` is always less that `RangeEnd`. Given by the current design policy of the DB you're working with it's worth double checking ;)

Comment: Since `Range` is silly someone might as well ask: what data type is `Count`? `'12'` is not between `'1'` and `'100'`, but `12` is between `1` and `100`. Tip: Include the DDL in SQL questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right off the bat I'm going to immediately suggest that you change your table structure to have separate columns for the lower and upper bounds of each range:

```
| ID | Count | lower_range | upper_range |
| 1  | 33    | 1           | 100         |
| 2  | 120   | 101         | 200         |
| 3  | 155   | 201         | 300         |
```

With this improved design, you only need a simple query:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE Count BETWEEN lower_range AND upper_range;
```

The advantages of this approach is that the above query is completely sargable (i.e. can use an index, should a suitable one be defined).  It also avoids your having to do some SQL olympics to isolate the lower and upper components of each hypenated range string.  Since your intention here is to work with those numbers as *numbers*, just use the above design instead.

**Edit:**

Here is a query you may use if you are really stuck with this design:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE
    Count BETWEEN CAST(SUBSTRING([Range], 1, CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) - 1) AS int) AND
                  CAST(SUBSTRING([Range], CHARINDEX('-', [Range]) + 1, LEN([Range])) AS int);
```

[image: screen capture of demo link below]

### Demo

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I could re-design it this would be the solution. Unfortunately I get all this out of a Salesforce API. I could ask the DB Admin of the DB where the data is imported to re-design its tables but this will take some time and I do need the validation asap.

Comment: @ruedi I gave you a workaround in this case, but you should consider it to be precisely just this: a workaround.  See if you can change your design at some point.

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible you can change structure of table add two columns for example
MinRange: int
MaxRange: int

```
SELECT *
FROM TableName
WHERE Count BETWEEN MinRange AND MaxRange
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to parse `Range` since it can have only one of three specific values:

```
-- Sample data (assuming that   Count   is not a string).
declare @Tabe as Table ( Id Int, [Count] Int, [Range] VarChar(10) );
insert into @Tabe ( Id, [Count], [Range] ) values
  ( 1, 33, '1-100' ), ( 2, 120, '101-200' ), ( 3, 155, '201-300' );
select * from @Tabe;

-- Using   case   expressions.
select *
  from @Tabe
  where [Count] between
    case Range
      when '1-100' then 1
      when '101-200' then 101
      when '201-300' then 201 end
    and
    case Range
      when '1-100' then 100
      when '101-200' then 200
      when '201-300' then 300 end;

-- Using an on-the-fly lookup table.
select T.*
  from @Tabe as T inner join
    ( values ( '1-100', 1, 100 ), ( '101-200', 101, 200 ), ( '201-300', 201, 300 ) )
      as Ranges( [Range], Low, High ) on T.[Range] = Ranges.[Range]
  where T.[Count] between Ranges.Low and Ranges.High;
```

Either approach fails nicely when `Range` has an unexpected value.